# toString blocking my main

Tags: java

I've nearly got this Java program working 100% as intended, but my toString method is causing the whole system to break down... apparently. Here are the two pieces of code which seem to be clashing.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main()
        {
            Ground ground = new Ground();
            ground.play();   
        }
}
```

that's the main function. fairly basic stuff. here's the play function:

```
public void play()
    {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(Ground.toString());
        while(i < 100 && isChestUnlocked() == false)
        {
            turn();
            System.out.println(Ground.toString());
            ++i;
        }
        System.out.print("You unlocked the treasure!");
    }
```

When I try to use it like this, bluej spits the dummy at me and claims that toString can't be referenced in a static context. How can I fix this? It feels like one of those "two characters are wrong" questions, and it's driving me nuts.

EDIT: If I change the Ground.toStrings to ground.toStrings, it claims it can't find the variable ground.

EDIT EDIT: Though I could swear it didn't work before, apparently this.toStrings works now. Thanks to ratchet for that!

Comment: Can you show your toString method?

Comment: BTW.  It would be more normal to write `!isChestUnlocked()` rather than `isChestUnlocked() == false`.  Also, to use a `for` loop: `for(int i=0; i<100 && !isChestUnlocked(); i++) { /* do loop body */ }` and get rid of `int i = 0;` and `++i`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove the `Ground` or replace with this.

```
public void play()
{
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(this.toString());
    while(i < 100 && isChestUnlocked() == false)
    {
        turn();
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        ++i;
    }
    System.out.print("You unlocked the treasure!");
}
```

`Ground` means the class while `this` is the current object the method is running on.

In fact just doing `System.out.println(this);` will work just as well. The [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.Object-) overload of `System.out` will invoke `toString` on the passed in object.

Comment: You can also just use `toString()` - or `this.toString()` - they mean the same thing in this code.

Answer (score 3):

```
 System.out.println(Ground.toString());
```

This calls `toString()` on the **class** rather than the object, which would require a static `toString()` which likely does not exist.

You need to change all instances of `Ground.toString()` to `this.toString()` or simply `toString()`, referring to the instance rather than the class.

Comment: Not really, since play is a method of Ground. he needs to just call it, or invoke it on this.

Comment: It then claims it can't find the variable ground. I'll move this piece of information to the main part.

Comment: @Stultuske right, didn'T catch that, I'll edit my answer to correct it